# Is there any svg path parameter indentation tool/editor or plugin for vscode?

Tags: css, svg, visual-studio-code

The title could be a little vague but the thing that I want to ask is I have a svg path like below but in order to edit/comprehend easier I want to display/indent as in the second snippet. Is there any indentation rules/editor or vscode plugin I can use ?

```
<path d="M213.1,6.7c-32.4-14.4-73.7,0-88.1,30.6C110.6,4.9,67.5-9.5,36.9,6.7C2.8,22.9-13.4,62.4,13.5,110.9
  C33.3,145.1,67.5,170.3,125,217c59.3-46.7,93.5-71.9,111.5-106.1C263.4,64.2,247.2,22.9,213.1,6.7z"/>
```

```
<path d="
  M 213.1,6.7
  c -32.4-14.4-73.7,0-88.1,30.6
  C 110.6,4.9,67.5-9.5,36.9,6.7
  C 2.8,22.9-13.4,62.4,13.5,110.9
  C 33.3,145.1,67.5,170.3,125,217
  c 59.3-46.7,93.5-71.9,111.5-106.1
  C 263.4,64.2,247.2,22.9,213.1,6.7
  z" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules)

Add the following setting.

```
  "replacerules.rules": {
    "svg-path": {
      "find": ["(?<!^ +)([MmLlHhVvCcSsQqTtAaZz]) *","(?<=^ +)([MmLlHhVvCcSsQqTtAaZz]) *"],
      "replace": ["\n  $1 ","$1 "]
    }
  },
```